# displaying the output of ByteArrayOutputStream as integer

Tags: java

the resulting output in the file fos1.txt is  d but i want it ti be 100 in the file , how can i do that?

```
public class Byteo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("G:\\fos1.txt");


            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int x = 100;

            bos.write(x);       


            try {

                bos.writeTo(fos1);

                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: can you make x a string ?

Comment: not worked. to be clear in my question the output is in ascii format and i want it to be in its original format.

Comment: are you sure? if you use instruction such as `bos.write(Integer.toString(x).getBytes());` you should have 100 in file

Comment: It is in its original format, but whatever you are using to read this as a text file will have to somewhat represent it as text, ASCII being chosen by default as it seems. As it is, your file is a binary file containing the byte `1100100`.

Comment: well this is due to fact that you not put 100 to file but string of it. if you want string representation to be present in text file, you cannot then read it as a byte stream. you have to read it as a strings

Comment: btw. why did it matter to view content file like you described? if this file was read by byte stream i guess it would read byte 100 even doe upon opening file in text editor you would see a `d` character?

Comment: I know that, text editor is just an example to simplify what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your int/Integer/char into String in order to not be interpreted as a byte code.

So you ends with `bos.write(String.valueOf(x).getBytes());`

Answer (score 2):

The `write(int b)` is interpreting the `int x = 100` as bytecode, therefore, writing the encoded byte to the file.

> write(int b) 
>   Writes the specified byte to this byte array output
>   stream.

You could do something like this:

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  int x = 100;
  bos.write(String.valueOf(x).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: You are correct, it's implemented in the superclass. This is the answer.

Comment: The author is attempting to write an integer as a String - using a String literal bypasses part of the question. Also, one shouldn't call getBytes() on a String in most cases - this will return the byte representation of the String in the VM default encoding. It is better to specify the encoding to avoid nasty surprises.

Comment: @JamesFry you are correct, I have changed to specify encoding.

Comment: Good stuff - better to use the StandardCharsets constants than string literals too.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a ByteArrayOutputStream here. A better approach is to use a writer, which handles much of the conversion for you, and to explicitly declare the encoding to use when converting from CharSequence to bytes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String path = "...";

  int x = 100;

  try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path),
      StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    writer.write(Integer.toString(x));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Something erred", e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Byteo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int x = 100;
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("fos1.txt");
        try {
            fw.write(String.valueOf(x));
        } finally {
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        }

    }
}
```